# Parsing Dictionary in python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have this XML which upon parsing gives dictionary with parent child relationship

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def remove_value(listOfDicts, key):
    for subVal in listOfDicts:
        if key in subVal:
            del subVal[key]

def get_children(parent):
    for child in parent:
        if "ACTION" in child.tag:
            continue
        if 'BOOLOP' in child.attrib:
            yield child.attrib['BOOLOP']
        else:
            yield child.attrib


def get_parent_children_mapping(tree):
    return { parent: list(get_children(parent)) for parent in tree.iter() if "ACTION" not in parent.tag }

s = """
  <RULE COMMENT="" DEFAULTPRIORITY="50" DESCRIPTION="DefaultShipping" DISABLEFLG="N" DefinedOutsideTree="true" FIRINGPHASE="" NAME="DefaultShipping" PATH="PB.SMB.DefaultShipping" RULECLASSIFICATION="PICK" TRIGGER="1">
            <BOOLOP BOOLOP="and" SEQ="0" TYPE="0">
                <BOOLOP BOOLOP="or" SEQ="1" TYPE="0">
                    <FRAGMENT FUNC1="value" FUNC2="propval" NULLACTION="Fragment is false" OP="=" PROP1="DEFAULT_SKU1" PROP2="_sku" SEQ="1" TYPE="1"/>
                    <FRAGMENT FUNC1="value" FUNC2="propval" NULLACTION="Fragment is false" OP="=" PROP1="DEFAULT_SKU2" PROP2="_sku" SEQ="2" TYPE="1"/>
                    <FRAGMENT FUNC1="value" FUNC2="propval" NULLACTION="Fragment is false" OP="=" PROP1="DEFAULT_SKU3" PROP2="_sku" SEQ="3" TYPE="1"/>
                </BOOLOP>
                <FRAGMENT FUNC1="propval" FUNC2="literal" NULLACTION="Fragment is false" OP="=" PROP1="_amEntitled" PROP2="1" SEQ="2" TYPE="1"/>
                <BOOLOP BOOLOP="and" SEQ="3" TYPE="0">
                    <FRAGMENT FUNC1="value" FUNC2="literal" NULLACTION="Fragment is true" OP="!=" PROP1="IsShipingSelected" PROP2="yes" SEQ="1" TYPE="1"/>
                    <FRAGMENT FUNC1="value" FUNC2="literal" NULLACTION="Fragment is true" OP="!=" PROP1="IsShipingSelected" PROP2="no" SEQ="2" TYPE="1"/>
                </BOOLOP>
            </BOOLOP>
            </RULE>
"""
entries = ['NULLACTION','SEQ','TYPE']
tree = ET.fromstring(s)
for parent, children in get_parent_children_mapping(tree).items():
    if children:
        for vals in entries:
            remove_value(children, vals)
        if 'NAME' in parent.attrib:
            print("{0} : {1}".format(parent.attrib['NAME'], children))


        elif 'BOOLOP' in parent.attrib:
            print("{0} : {1}".format(parent.attrib['BOOLOP'], children))

        else:
            print("{0} : {1}".format(parent.tag, children))
```

The program prints a output like this upon iterating over the items:

**OUTPUT**:

```
DefaultShipping : ['and']
    and : ['or', {'FUNC1': 'propval', 'FUNC2': 'literal', 'OP': '=', 'PROP1': '_amEntitled', 'PROP2': '1'}, 'and']
    or : [{'FUNC1': 'value', 'FUNC2': 'propval', 'OP': '=', 'PROP1': 'DEFAULT_SKU1', 'PROP2': '_sku'}, {'FUNC1': 'value', 'FUNC2': 'propval', 'OP': '=', 'PROP1': 'DEFAULT_SKU2', 'PROP2': '_sku'}, {'FUNC1': 'value', 'FUNC2': 'propval', 'OP': '=', 'PROP1': 'DEFAULT_SKU3', 'PROP2': '_sku'}]
    and : [{'FUNC1': 'value', 'FUNC2': 'literal', 'OP': '!=', 'PROP1': 'IsShipingSelected', 'PROP2': 'yes'}, {'FUNC1': 'value', 'FUNC2': 'literal', 'OP': '!=', 'PROP1': 'IsShipingSelected', 'PROP2': 'no'}]
```

The output depicts the parent child relationship. Now I want to further manipulate the output as something like this:

`(FUNC1(PROP1) OP FUNC2(PROP2) and FUNC1(PROP1) OP FUNC2(PROP2)) or (FUNC1(PROP1) OP FUNC2(PROP2))`

Is there something inbuilt in parser or do I need to write my own parser. Any help is appreciated.

**NOTE**

In my output example by FUNC1, FUNC2,PROP1 etc. I mean their values.

Thanks to @ Martijn Pieters for guiding about the Syntax trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no in-built parser, nor do you need a parser. You need to build a [syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), which is not that hard:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, fields
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Node:
    seq: int
    type: int

    @classmethod
    def tree_from_xml(cls, node):
        name = node.tag
        for cls in cls.__subclasses__():
            if cls.__name__.upper() == name:
                return cls.node_from_xml(node)

    @classmethod
    def node_from_xml(cls, node, **kwargs):
        fieldargs = {f.name: node.attrib.get(f.name.upper()) for f in fields(cls)}
        fieldargs['seq'] = int(fieldargs['seq'])
        fieldargs['type'] = int(fieldargs['type'])
        fieldargs.update(kwargs)
        return cls(**fieldargs)

@dataclass
class BoolOp(Node):
    boolop: str
    operands: List[Node] = field(default_factory=list)

    def __str__(self):
        joined = f' {self.boolop} '.join(map(str, self.operands))
        return f'({joined})'

    @classmethod
    def node_from_xml(cls, node):
        operands = (Node.tree_from_xml(child) for child in node)
        return super().node_from_xml(node, operands=[op for op in operands if op])

@dataclass
class Fragment(Node):
    func1: str
    func2: str
    nullaction: str
    op: str
    prop1: str
    prop2: str

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.func1}({self.prop1}) {self.op} {self.func2}({self.prop2})'
```

then build those objects from the top-level `BOOLOP` XML node, and print the result:

```
rule = Node.tree_from_xml(tree.find('.//BOOLOP'))
print(rule)
```

Note that `rule` is a `Node` subclass, so you can still inspect the tree directly, or call `str()` on that object to get the string conversion.

Demo:

```
>>> rule = Node.tree_from_xml(tree.find('.//BOOLOP'))
>>> print(rule)
((value(DEFAULT_SKU1) = propval(_sku) or value(DEFAULT_SKU2) = propval(_sku) or value(DEFAULT_SKU3) = propval(_sku)) and propval(_amEntitled) = literal(1) and (value(IsShipingSelected) != literal(yes) and value(IsShipingSelected) != literal(no)))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I will definitely read more about syntax trees. I just have one question. This is the link to my [complete xml](https://shrib.com/#vAOqj35vgZ3kQNEZ9NV5). I was  doing that because I need to find iterate through the rule tag and get all the set of properties (i.e rule definition) and then find which is triggered based on what property attached at item.

Comment: But thanks for the help. I have been trying to achieve this from past week. At first I even tried to convert the xml to JSON but that was a painful work. So I switched back to xml

Comment: @Duck_dragon right; by keeping the rule structures as trees you can add functionality to those nodes as needed, and perhaps add more nodes to cover more XML tags, it all depends on your end goals. If you need to match rules against a specific set of values then adding the ability to evaluate each rule would make sense, for example.

Comment: I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tag'` if I write `findall` instead of find. Basically I need to get all the rules based on certain criteria. I have but the edited code in my question

Comment: @Duck_dragon the base idea is that *expressions* are hierarchical structures, and if you need to reason about them then using a tree structure of nodes containing nodes makes your job easier, especially when those nodes are classes with functionality.

Comment: @Duck_dragon: `Node.tree_from_xml()` expects a *single XML element*, don’t pass in a list.

Comment: @Duck_dragon: look at how the `operands` list is built, using loops.

Comment: Now I got it . I will pass singe element inside the Node Class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189773/discussion-between-duck-dragon-and-martijn-pieters).